# Quantum distance ladder

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, education

There is a [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ne0GArfeMs) on how facts about the cosmos can be derived form rather simple observation. Is there an analogy for the small scale? Is there a technically simple observation that would imply, say, atoms? Anything smaller?

Comment: Concerning question based on videos, see [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4918/2451) meta post.

Comment: @Qmechanic, The lecture explains how Greeks measured the radius of earth, then used that to measure the distance to the moon, then used that to measure the distance to the sun, etc. I assumed that my question would be clear without watching the lecture.

Comment: Brownian motion was historically the smoking gun that proved Dalton's atomic theory beyond a shadow of a doubt. But any chemist worth his NaCl already knew that matter had to be made of atoms.